# Separating Numeric values from Text Values

Tags: android, text, separator, textutils

I am retrieving information from a REST API and it displays:

```
"Per 78g - Calories: 221kcal | Fat: 12.65g | Carbs: 16.20g | Protein: 10.88g"
```

I have imported the items into a ListView and when a user clicks an item I would like to string each numeric value individually like below without their text. Based on the example above:

```
String calories = 221;
String fat = 12.65;
String carbs = 16.20;
String protein = 10.88;
```

I got rid of the "Per 78g" with:

```
String sd = food.getString("food_description");
String[] row = sd.split("-");
tems.add(new Item(food.getString("food_name"), row[1]));
```

Which displays the following in each list item.

```
"Calories: 221kcal | Fat: 12.65g | Carbs: 16.20g | Protein: 10.88g"
```

When the User clicks on a list Item:  How do I separate this properly and eliminate the text as well?  Once I get the numeric values individually I would be fine.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String calories = adapter.getItem(arg2).getDescription();

    String[] calRow = calories.split("?|?");

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + calRow[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mCallback.onFoodSelected(adapter.getItem(arg2).getTitle(), calRow[1]);
}
```

The API documentation is really bad and outdated.  I am using it because it has great information.
For everyone that believes this is bad practice this is the example return JSON:

```
{  
   "foods":{  
      "food":{  
         "food_description":"Per 342g - Calories: 835kcal | Fat: 32.28g | Carbs: 105.43g | Protein: 29.41g",
         "food_id":"4384",
         "food_name":"Plain French Toast",
         "food_type":"Generic",
         "food_url":"http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/generic\/french-toast-plain"
      },
      "max_results":"20",
      "page_number":"0",
      "total_results":"228"
   }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this already working? The `calRow[1]` part doesn't already contain what you want? Or you want to get rid of the units as well? Did you try regular expressions?

Comment: Why not just format your JSON from the API? This is clearly a bad practice.

Comment: @heltonbiker I want the list items to display the the calRow[1].  When the user clicks it I want to separate the values for equations.

Comment: @LazyNinja I did format he JSON from the API.  This is the returning value.

Comment: Try using Android [Pattern](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for that.

Comment: @heltonbiker Going to read up on it now and get back to you.

Comment: @EugeneH Try the json format, I have posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your JSON as follows, will make your job more easier:

```
{  
   "foods":{  
      "food":{  
         "food_description":{
            "Per" : "342g",
            "Calories": "835kcal",
            " Fat": "32.28g",
            "Carbs":" 105.43g",
            " Protein": "29.41g"
            },
         "food_id":"4384",
         "food_name":"Plain French Toast",
         "food_type":"Generic",
         "food_url":"http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/generic\/french-toast-plain"
      },
      "max_results":"20",
      "page_number":"0",
      "total_results":"228"
   }
}
```

I am assuming you know how to parse it.
And in case you are not able to change your json, try to use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) or use String.split().

Comment: I ended up Using the String Tokenizer. I got it to work thanks.