# Separating Numeric Values from string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having an issue, whereby I need to separate the following `BPO007` to show `BPO` and `007`. In some cases another example would be `GFE0035`, whereby I still need to split the numeric value from the characters.

When I do the following `select isnumeric('BPO007')` the result is 0, which is correct, however, I'm not sure how split these from each other.

I've had a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540541/separating-numeric-values-from-text-values), but it does not really answer my question.

I need the above split for a separate validation purpose in my trigger.

How would I develop something like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: `SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'BPO007')`, `LEFT`, `SUBSTRING`.

Comment: Jeroen Mostert has given all the needed tools in his comment. About your question *How would I develop something like this?*: Do not store two pieces of information within the same column (read about *1.NF*). You should keep separate columns in your database for `BPO` and for `007` (or rather `7`) and use some string methods to *compute* the `BPO007` when you need in in your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told in a comment before:

About your question *How would I develop something like this?*:
Do not store two pieces of information within the same column (read about *1.NF*). You should keep separate columns in your database for *BPO* and for *007* (or rather an integer *7*).
Then use some string methods to compute the *BPO007* when you need it in your output.

Just not to let you alone in the rain.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourColumn VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('BPO007'),('GFE0035');

SELECT YourColumn,pos
      ,LEFT(YourColumn,pos) AS CharPart
      ,CAST(SUBSTRING(YourColumn,pos+1,1000) AS INT) AS NumPart
FROM @tbl 
CROSS APPLY(SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',YourColumn)-1) AS A(pos);
```

Will return

```
YourColumn  pos CharPart    NumPart
BPO007      3   BPO         7
GFE0035     3   GFE         35
```

Hint: I use a `CROSS APPLY` here to compute the position of the first numeric character and then use `pos` in the actual query like you'd use a variable. Otherwise the `PATINDEX` would have to be repeated...

Comment: Thanks Shnugo, I will try this and revert.

Comment: Thanks Shnugo, this was exactly what I was looking for - works like a charm!

Comment: Hi Shnugo, you are correct. Apologies, I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number and text varies, you can use the following codes

```
DECLARE @NUMERIC TABLE (Col VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @NUMERIC VALUES('BPO007'),('GFE0035'),('GFEGVT003509'),('GFEMTS10035')

SELECT
Col,
LEFT(Col,LEN(Col)-LEN(SUBSTRING(Col,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Col),DATALENGTH(Col)))) AS TEXTs,
RIGHT(Col,LEN(Col)-LEN(LEFT(Col,LEN(Col)-LEN(SUBSTRING(Col,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Col),DATALENGTH(Col)))))) AS NUMERICs

FROM @NUMERIC
```

Comment: Thanks JonWay, I don't think it will always by 3 characters as it's based on the user preference, but thanks for your answer.